# Robot Framework - Selecting value from a dropdown list which appears after mouse over

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-ide

The scenario is :

1. The user will move the mouse over the link : ID_CHECK: R17AA003
2. The dropdown list will appear automatically
3. User will select a test type from the list by Clicking

[image]

I am trying this code to achieve this :

```
Mouse over    ${xpathToIdCheck}
Page Should Contain Element    xpath=//*[@id="list_of_test_types"]    5s
Click Element   ${User_Menu Link}
Select From List    xpath=//*[@id="list_of_test_types"]    STR
```

When I run the test, Robot framework moves the mouse over the id_Check link and we can see that the text box is appearing:

[image]

But right after that the test fails. Apparently it can find the element on the webpage , but can not locate the dropdown box to click on.

[image]

After this I tried by removing the click link command and directly went for Select from list command:

```
Mouse over    ${xpathToIdCheck}
Page Should Contain Element    xpath=//*[@id="list_of_test_types"]    5s
Select From List    xpath=//*[@id="list_of_test_types"]    STR
```

But it failed again. The feedback is as follows:

[image]

The html code is as follows:

```
    <form action="/change_test_type_id_check?page=1&amp;study_id=ID&amp;test_uuid=UUID" method="post" style="display:inline">
    <select class="list_of_test_types" id="list_of_test_types" name="`" onchange="this.form.submit()">
<option value="">Select a test type</option>
<option value="STR">STR</option></select>
    </form>
```

Also if I change the code to

```
Select From List by Value   xpath=//*[@id="list_of_test_types"]    STR
```

This also fails with the message "NoSuchElementException: Message: Cannot locate option with value: STR"

Looking forward for your kind support. Thanks

Comment: Do you find any solution? 
I suggest that you use autoIt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try as below.

```
Mouse over    ${xpathToIdCheck}
Page Should Contain Element    xpath=//*[@id="list_of_test_types"]    5s
Click Element   ${User_Menu Link}
Mouse Down    xpath=//li[contains(.,'${STR}')]
Click Element  xpath=//li[contains(.,'${STR}')]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46682932/how-can-i-get-all-elements-of-autocomplete-list-with-robotframework
Could you please see this question, a similar problem but in desktop application automation.

Comment: Thanks. I only had to modify the xpath as xpath=//option[contains(.,'STR')]

Answer (score 1):

try to use this

```
    Select From List By Index    name:Trail.NationalParkId    1
```

[image]